# When printing my web page it has some margin issues

Tags: html, css

So when i'll try to print out my document it will start colliding and does not show it the same as it shows in browser. Is there a workaround which wouldn't involve changing any of my css schema just for in case of printing?

[image: http://imgur.com/ggH8Lf1]

As seen from image (i don't have enough rep to post it as image) there is a lot of room in the top and in the sides. I don't understand why is that like this, although i turned margins in the settings to 0 when choosing printing options.

In browser the rows are bigger and no collision.

I don't know if code is needed at this point but could also provide if needed.

Comment: Can you please reproduce your problem in jsFiddle and post the link here?

Comment: i have my page uploaded on http://kevin.planet.ee/16table.html
this has the table on it, just print preview and it shows

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use  media queries just for printing

```
  @media print{
  //You can do anything you want here and it will only affect the printed       pages.
// Just use normal CSS.
//You can even put the unit cm to a good use here.  
  }
```